# Python:Write list value into the file

Tags: python

Need help in the below code:

```
langs=['C','Java','Cobol','Python']

f1=open('a.txt','r')

f2=open('abc.txt','w')

for index in range(len(langs)):

    for line in f1:

        f2.write(line.replace('Frst languag','langs[index]'))

f1.close()

f2.close()
```

Line #4: 
Not sure if the syntax is correct, all i want is the loop to run for n number of times where n is no. of values inside the list.

Line 6:
All I need is everytime the loop to run and each time `langs[0]` value #should be written to the file, then `langs[1]` value and so on...

Comment: your `range(len(langs))` and referring to `langs[index]` is an anti-pattern in Python. 
 
Just use
`for lang in langs:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f2.write(line.replace('Frst languag','{}'.format(langs[index]))
```

Comment: `'{}'.format(langs[index])` is the obfuscated version of `langs[index]`.

Comment: @Matthias very true. Didn't know if the OP had different intentions when specifically using string interpolation (`'language {}'.format(...`)